# Getting only visible projects while JIRA plugin development

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I'm developing a JIRA plugin. I want to get all visible projects for a specified user. When I use projectManager.getProjectObjects(), it returns all projects. But I want to get only projects which are visible and accessible and browse-able by specified User.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`PermissionManager.getProjectObjects(Permissions.BROWSE, user)`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/security/PermissionManager.html#getProjects(int,%20com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser)) (or one of the other methods with the same name in that class, depending on the exact version of JIRA you are targeting).